# tail -f implementation in node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, readfile, watch, tail

I have created an implementation of tail -f in node.js using socket.io and fs.watch function.

I read the file using `fs.readFile`, convert it into array of lines and returns it to the client. Stores the current length in variable.
Then whenever the "file changed" event fires, I re-read the whole file, converts it into array of lines. And then compare the old length and current length. and slice it like

```
fileContent.slice(oldLength, fileContent.length)
```

this gives me the changed content. So running perfectly fine.

Problem: I am reading the whole file every time the file gets changed, which is not efficient if file is too large. So is there any way, of reading a file once, and then gets the changed content if there is any change?

I have also tried, spawning child process for "tail -f"

```
var spawn = require ('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn ('tail', ['-f', logfile]);
   child.stdout.on ('data', function (data){
   linesArray = data.toString().split("\n")
   console.log ( "Data sent" + linesArray[0]);

   io.emit('changed', {
      data: linesArray,
   });
});
```

the problem with this is:

1. on("data") event fires multiple time when I save the logfile by writing some content.
2. On first load, it correctly returns the last ten line of the file. But if there is a change then it return the whole content again and again.

So if you have any idea of solving this problem let me know. Till then I will dig the internet.

Comment: Have you considered using a package like [`tail`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tail)?

Comment: Yes, but I would rather like to stick to my own implementation, rather than depending on external npm package. I want something native.

Comment: But existing modules can serve as an example on how to implement something similar.

Comment: Yeah, I am reading the codebase of existing packages. That's where I got the code of spawning child process. I have already implemented the feature. But just wanted to know if there is way to avoid "reading file" every time it gets changed. That is not a big thing.

Comment: Looking at some implementations, they seem to work by keeping track of the file size. When it changes, they use the _previous_ file size as a starting point to start reading the file again, thereby only reading the part of the file that was appended since the last time it was read. Another option would be to open/read the file using `fs.open()/fs.read()`, and only read the newly appended data (again, by tracking file size changes).

Comment: Yeah already saw this somewhere. Using it.Using fstat to get the size of the file and creating new buffer and then calling it through fs.read.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep for helping.

Comment: Unless this is for academic reasons, one of the biggest advantages of node.js is the huge set of NPM modules that you can use and/or learn from and you'd be missing much of the reason for using node.js in the first place if you categorically refused to use code other people have developed.  FYI, an efficient implementation of tail (which will make a huge difference on large files) will read chunks from the end of the file to find the last N lines and not search from the beginning.

Comment: Agree with you. But I am a type of guy, who would like to do things from scratch to gain more insights of the core language, so that I can invent things and debug easily next time. I never used jquery/Angular directly, first I learned javascript. Or before going into RoR, I learned ruby and socket programming. I like to create things from scratch so that I can add/extend its feature easily since I have written it. I dont wanna depend on libraries if I don't need most of its features. Sometimes I use it sometimes I don't :) And yeah I am also reading only the chunk of content now that changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I got the solution by reading someone else's code. So solution was to use fs.open which will open the file and then instead of reading whole file we can read the particular block from the file using fs.read() function.
To know about the fs.open/fs.read, read this [nodejs-file-system](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-file-system).

Official doc : [fs.read](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)